# Shorthand computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Can anyone please explain why these don't evaluate to the same thing?

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    maxProducts: 5,

    hasMaxProducts: function () {
        return this.get('model.length') === this.get('maxProducts');
    }.property('model.length'),

    shorthandHasMaxProducts: Ember.computed.equal('model.length', 'maxProducts')
});
```

I'm using the `hasMaxProducts` property in a handlebars template successfully, and if I try switching to the `shorthandHasMaxProducts` property, I don't get the same results, nor does it seem that this property ever updates. This should happen when I add another model to the array collection. I've also tried computing with:

```
Ember.computed.equal('model.[]', 'maxProducts')
Ember.computed.equal('model.[].length', 'maxProducts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `Ember.computed.equal` cannot be a property name, it has to be a plain javascript value, so a string, integer, boolean etc.

http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_equal

Comment: Is `maxProducts` considered computed? it's setup as a plain integer

Comment: You are right, what I meant is that it may not be a property name, it has to be a value. So in this case you have to use the `hasMaxProducts`.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. So ember is comparing the length to the string `'maxProducts'` then